# Water leaking into dishwasher continuously

Tags: dishwasher, leaks

My dishwasher seems to be continually filling with clean water. The cycle runs fine and the dishwasher can drain. However inspecting it I see water is slowly tricking in through this part.
[image: inside]

When moving the dishwasher I see the water is right below this loop and I I am not quite sure how to fix it. Here are some photos
[image: outside]

When I turn the water off, the level does go down. But I’m not sure where or what to check that’s causing this.

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: Would look in the manual/parts for a water inlet valve, it is probably leaking and needs replacement.  Keep outside water valve turned off till you are using the dishwasher.

Comment: @crip659 will do! Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 2):

The solenoid valve that controls the water probably has some scale or rust stuck in it.

With the power and water turned off the valves can usually be repaired by dissembling cleaning and reassembled, dish washers and washing machines have screens many times to stop the debris from getting in the valve and causing a flood.

If you clean it or replace it I would suggest adding a screen element to prevent this from happening in the future.

The only negative to a screen is after a few years you may notice the machine taking a long time to fill or an error on some machines, simple fix for this turn the water off pull the screen and flush water through it in the opposite direction and this flushed the debris out and it can be re installed, some types need to be replaced as they won’t seal but they are cheap I think the last pair I got was about 3$ for 2,

Comment: Yes, the slightest bit of scales can prevent the valve from totally closing.

Comment: A good thing to check.  I had a piece of solder stuck in my water solenoid that caused issues.